# CloneNode Error When Session Set Values in Meteor

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

In My Meteor Project Session Set Array of Mapping Functions Return CloneNode Error!. Code is Here

```
   var SubCategory = $(':checkbox[name=SubCategory]:checked').map(function() {


});

console.log(SubCategory);
Session.set( "subCategory", SubCategory);
```

And Console Output Here

```
["category1", "category2", prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[2]]
```

Error in Console:`Uncaught TypeError: elem.cloneNode is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Solve This Question.

```
SubCategory(event){
let checked = event.target.checked;
let subcategory= [];
var SubCategory = $(':checkbox[name=SubCategory]:checked').map(function(value,index) {

   subcategory.push(index.value);

 });
Session.set( "subCategory", subcategory);
}
```

Result in console:

```
["category1", "category2"]
```